# awk command to read a key value pair from a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file `input.txt` which stores information in `KEY:VALUE` form. I'm trying to read `GOOGLE_URL` from this `input.txt` which prints only `http` because the seperator is `:`. What is the problem with my `grep` command and how should I print the entire URL.

**SCRIPT**

```
$> cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
URL=`grep -e '\bGOOGLE_URL\b' input.txt | awk -F: '{print $2}'`
printf " $URL \n"
```

**INPUT_FILE**

```
$> cat input.txt
GOOGLE_URL:https://www.google.com/
```

**OUTPUT**

```
https
```

**DESIRED_OUTPUT**

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple `:` in your input, getting `$2` will not work in `awk` because it will just give you 2nd field. You actually need an equivalent of `cut -d: -f2-` but you also need to check key name that comes before first `:`.

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk -F: '$1 == "GOOGLE_URL" {sub(/^[^:]+:/, "");  print}' input.txt

https://www.google.com/
```

Or this non-regex `awk` approach that allows you to pass key name from command line:

```sh
awk -F: -v k='GOOGLE_URL' '$1==k{print substr($0, length(k FS)+1)}' input.txt
```

Or using `gnu-grep`:

```sh
grep -oP '^GOOGLE_URL:\K.+' input.txt

https://www.google.com/
```

Comment: @Yash: Did you make sense of why our attempt didn't work?

Comment: Hi Inian, I don't see your solution now. Kindly repost it. I will check and update you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This will look for string `GOOGLE_URL` and will catch further either http or https value from url, in case you need only `https` then change `http[s]?` to `https` in following solution please.

```
awk '/^GOOGLE_URL:/{match($0,/http[s]?:\/\/.*/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
/^GOOGLE_URL:/{                     ##Checking condition if line starts from GOOGLE_URL: then do following.
  match($0,/http[s]?:\/\/.*/)       ##Using match function to match http[s](s optional) : till last of line here.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Printing sub string of matched value from above function.
}
' Input_file                        ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you need anything coming after first `:` then try following.

```
awk '/^GOOGLE_URL:/{match($0,/:.*/);print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

```
$ sed -n 's/^GOOGLE_URL://p' file
https://www.google.com/

$ awk 'sub(/^GOOGLE_URL:/,"")' file
https://www.google.com/
```

The above will work using any sed or awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way for that task:
Let `file.txt` content be:

```
EXAMPLE_URL:http://www.example.com/
GOOGLE_URL:https://www.google.com/
KEY:GOOGLE_URL:
```

Then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="^GOOGLE_URL:"}{if(NF==2){print $2}}' file.txt
```

will output:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Explanation: GNU `AWK` `FS` might be pattern, so I set it to `GOOGLE_URL:` anchored (`^`) to begin of line, so `GOOGLE_URL:` in middle/end will not be seperator (consider 3rd line of input). With this `FS` there might be either 1 or 2 fields in each line - latter is case only if line starts with `GOOGLE_URL:` so I check number of fields (`NF`) and if this is second case I print 2nd field (`$2`) as first record in this case is empty.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: There;'s nothing specific to GNU awk there, every awk has a regexp (not "pattern" - that term is meaningless) as the `FS`.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another `awk` alternative:

```
gawk -F'(^[^:]*:)' '/^GOOGLE_URL:/{ print $2 }' infile
```